# UIScrollView not working properly even with a set height

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a `UIScrollView` attached to a `UIViewController` that has help text in it. I set the height of the view inside a script but it can just be scrolled horizontally even though I set the labels to multiple lines. I want to be able to scroll down to be able to see the rest of the help text.

In other words, how can I enable vertical scrolling in a `UIScrollView`?

```
import UIKit

class HelpController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think you should be setting contentSize width. Refer this - https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Thank you, that solved it. If you post an answer to this question, I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think you should be using frames for dynamic content. Try with autolayout like how this guide says

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/